# More efficient way of using javascript to stick columns to bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been designing a web site for a while, its a two column layout, and I want each column to go to the bottom of the page regardless of resolution. Currently to accomplish this, I have two JavaScript files - One that adjusts the column length to fit the browser window, and the other JavaScript file is to match the resized one. One major problem I have, is that if you change the browser window size, the columns do no auto adjust, so they may not go to the bottom of the page. I am wondering if there is some way I could do this all in one file, and most importantly make the columns always stick to the bottom of the page no matter what the window size is. Here is the code for each JavaScript file:

Adjust column height to browser window:

```
$(function(){
    var grid = $(window).height();
    var gridFinal = grid - 140;
    $('.grid').css({'min-height': ((gridFinal))+'px'});
});
```

Adjust the other column to match the resized one:

```
window.onload =  getIDHeight;

function getIDHeight() {
    var myHomeHeight = document.getElementById("home").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("home-services").style.height = myHomeHeight - 15 +"px";
}


window.addEventListener('load', function (){

var myNewsHeight = document.getElementById("blog").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("social-media").style.height = myNewsHeight - 15 +"px";
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){

var myAboutHeight = document.getElementById("references").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("about").style.height = myAboutHeight - 25 +"px";
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){

var myServicesHeight = document.getElementById("services").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("guidelines").style.height = myServicesHeight - 15 +"px";
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){

var myTipsHeight = document.getElementById("tips").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("recommendations").style.height = myTipsHeight - 20 +"px";
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){

var myContactHeight = document.getElementById("contact-info").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("email").style.height = myContactHeight - 15 +"px";
});
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. If there is a simpler way of doing this that increases functionality, please let me know.

Comment: Just a thought:  If you can live with "bottom of the *window*", as opposed to "bottom of the *page*", there's `position: fixed`.

Comment: is there a reason one file uses jquery and the other doesn't?

Comment: Not really, I am not super savvy when it comes to JS and jQuery, I just went with what I could find, and understand. Also, the footer must stay fixed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with CSS. Set the height of html & body to 100%, then set the columns to height 100%

Fiddle here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7G5LQ/)

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
#column1{
    height:100%;
}
#column2{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that works, as I am using a fixed footer, and I am putting the columns inside a wrapper. I've tried 100% heights before, but they do not work.